# Why is my Kubernetes watcher returning ADDED events for very old resources?

Tags: kubernetes

I ran the following script to watch namespaces:

```
config.load_kube_config()
v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
w = watch.Watch()
for event in w.stream(v1.list_namespace, _request_timeout=60):
    print("Event: %s %s" % (event["type"], event["object"].metadata.name))
```

When I run it, it returns `Event: ADDED <NAMESPACE>` for every namespace on the cluster. Even for namespaces that were created years ago.

I thought k8s removed events after about an hour. Why am I seeing an ADDED event for a namespace that was created years ago?

Does it keep the last event a resource has sent forever?

How long does k8s hang on to DELETE events from removed resources?

Answer (score 0):

thanks.
Maybe you need watch with param resourceversion.

Comment: refer to https://www.baeldung.com/java-kubernetes-watch

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34609930)